# Construct a function g which increases faster than all $f_n$ for $n \in \Bbb{N}$

Tags: calculus, general-topology, proof-verification

Let $f_n : \Bbb{N} \rightarrow \Bbb{N}$ $(n \in \Bbb{N})$ be a fixed collection of functions. Construct a function $g : \Bbb{N} \rightarrow \Bbb{N}$ such that for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$,
$lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} = \frac{g(k)}{f_n(k)} = \infty$
Not too sure about this question; one thing that came to mind was letting $g(k) = nf_n(k)$ Is this okay ?

Comment: The problem is that $n$ is not specified in $g(k) = nf_n(k)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost. Try $g(k)=k\sum_{n\leq k}f_n(k)$.

Let $n$ be given. Let $N>0$. Let $k>\max \{n,N\}$.

Then $\frac{g(k)}{f_n(k)}\geq k>N.$ This proves $\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{g(k)}{f_n(k)}=\infty$

Comment: How does the inequality of the quotient being greater than k follow?